# Capacitor CDE part number request

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, identification, components

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anybody know what this capacitor's CDE part number is?

It's for my car sound amplifier and I have to change this capacitor, but I don’t know its exact part number for ordering.

Comment: What is "CDE number?" Cornell Dubilier? How can you tell it's made by them? (And in case you know why not just ask their tech support)

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a mixture there. The one in the second picture is a Nichicon 100uF 35V WD series. I suspect in all other cases the number in the middle is the value in uF but voltage ratings will be harder to determine without identifying the manufacturer.